# "so many" vs "too many" in a particular case

Tags: grammar

> I had **too** many things to do that I couldn’t finish them all 
>   I had **so** many things to do that I couldn’t finish them all

What is correct? My teacher said that it is the second one but in my opinion, the first one fits better because of the phrase

> I couldn’t finish them all

Comment: Related question, [Is “He is too weak that he cannot walk” a correct sentence?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/75816/is-he-is-too-weak-that-he-cannot-walk-a-correct-sentence/75823#75823).

Answer (score 1):

[i] * *I had too many things to do **that I couldn’t finish them all***

[ii] *I had so many things to do **that I couldn’t finish them all***

There is a grammatical explanation for "so" being correct and not "too". The clause in bold is a **delayed complement.** It's called 'delayed' because it does not immediately follow the element that licenses it, but is 'delayed' to the end of the sentence (the matrix clause). In your example [ii], the delayed complement is licensed by the adverb "so" that modifies "many things". But "too" cannot licence a *that* clause complement in a construction like this, which is why [i] is ungrammatical.

You can tell that it's "so" that licenses the complement because if we drop it, the sentence becomes ungrammatical (* *I had many things to do that I couldn’t finish them all).*

Comment: Could you explain what the complements "that I couldn’t finish them all" are completing?

Comment: @Roaring Fish It's a complement in clause structure.

Comment: Okay, but complements complete. That is why they are called complements, and as such cannot be removed from the sentence as it would be left, by definition, incomplete. "That I couldn’t finish them all" doesn't complete anything that I can see, and can be removed to leave complete sentence: "I had too/so many things to do".

Comment: @Roaring Fish No, complements have to be licensed by some element. The _that_ clause in the OP's example is licensed by _so_. Complements may be optional or obligatory.

Comment: From here > http://semanticsarchive.net/Archive/GZhNGUxZ/dowty.Oslo.pdf "a complement is an “obligatory element” [...]*a complement “completes” the meaning of its head." From here > http://www.ucd.ie/artspgs/introling/engsyndraft.pdf "‘complement’ refers to an obligatory dependent clause or phrase relative to a head." From wikipedia: "a complement can be understood as a word, phrase or clause that is necessary to complete the meaning of a given expression." As the example clause can be removed, it is neither completing anything nor obligatory. How do you justify calling it a complement?

Comment: @Roaring Fish Obligatory items are always complements, but complements may or may not be obligatory. A direct object is a type of complement, but not all objects are obligatory. For example, in _Jill paid the bill_, the object (a complement) is _the bill_ but it's not obligatory. You can have just _Jill paid_. Virtually all _that_ clauses are complements and many of them are optional.

Comment: "a complement is an obligatory element" and "complement refers to an obligatory independent clause" seem clear to me, and contradict your "may or may not be obligatory", but leaving that aside, in *Jill paid the bill*, *the bill* is completing what was paid. What is "that I couldn’t finish them all" completing?

Comment: @Roaring Fish I didn't say anything contradictory. Again, obligatory items are always complements, but not all complements are obligatory. In _Jill paid the bill_ the object _bill_ is a complement, but it's not obligatory. You can say it 'completes the meaning', but grammatically it’s clearly optional. Similarly, the clause _That I couldn't finish them all_ is a complement in that it has to be licensed (permitted) by some element, in this case "so", but it is clearly optional. Of course it adds some meaning to the verb phrase, but it's still an optional complement, not an obligatory one.

Comment: I think you are confused about what "obligatory" means, and that is why you are insisting that "a compliment is an obligatory element" really means "a compliment is *sometimes* an obligatory element". A complete idea=head+complement. In *Jane paid the bill* the complete idea is that the bill was paid by Jane. It requires *Jane paid+the bill* to be complete. *Jane paid* is not the same idea so *the bill* is not optional. You say repeatedly that "so" governs "that I couldn’t finish them all", yet when I ask - three times now - what the  complete idea is you refuse to answer.

Comment: @Roaring Fish I did NOT say that a complement is an obligatory item! I said that obligatory items are always complements. There is a difference! Yes, complements are often optional. You are confusing meaning with grammar. “The bill” is GRAMMATICALLY optional. Consider: _She paid the bill with her credit card_. The PP _with her credit card_ adds some meaning to the VP; ‘completes the thought’ if you like, but is it obligatory? Of course not; it’s an adjunct, an entirely optional item, not even a complement. You must distinguish meaning from what is grammatically obligatory or otherwise.

Comment: @Roaring Fish A key element of the definition of ‘complement’ is that it applies to elements which are within the 'valency' of a verb or other lexical unit. By 'valency', we mean 'the range of syntactic elements either required or specifically permitted by a verb or other lexical unit’ – which is equivalent to licensing. Note the words 'required or specifically permitted' which we can take as meaning obligatory or otherwise.

Comment: You said complements are not obligatory which is contradicted by the links I supplied. If you think "the bill" is optional, give me a sentence that says the bill was paid by Jane without mentioning the bill. "Jane paid" doesn't do it because that could be used if she paid the taxi driver, her employee, a fine, or anything else so it is a different sentence expressing a different idea. And... you are still refusing to explain what "that I couldn't finish them all" is completing. If it isn't completing anything then it isn't a complement by definition.

Comment: @Roaring Fish How many times do I have to say this: "THE BILL" IS GRAMMATICALLY OPTIONAL. And I'm not refusing anything. I never said "that I couldn't finish them all" was completing anything; YOU DID!

Comment: The *defining* element is that it completes an idea. You can't say what the idea is that is being completed in the example sentences. As a complement completes an idea, it is also, by definition, obligatory which is why you cannot express the idea of a bill being paid by Jane with mentioning the bill. Valency is irrelevant. That is a property of a verb, not a complement, and it is not the same as licensing.

Comment: ... If it is not completing anything, *then it is not a complement* and your answer is wrong.

Comment: @Roaring Fish I give up. You clearly have a great deal to learn about English grammar; far more than I have the space or inclination to explain to you here. Incidentally, valency has precisely to do with the complements a verb has, e.g. “He read the paper" is bivalent because it has two COMPLEMENTS, the subject and the object. And if you read my earlier message properly, you’ll see that I actually said ‘required or specifically permitted by a verb or other syntactic unit’. Nouns, adjectives and prepositions, for example take complements, as well as verbs.

Comment: You seem to be using words without being clear what they mean. Verbs have valency. They also have complements. Prepositions have no valency. They can have complements. Logically, valency and complement action cannot be the same thing. Why did Tesniere call verb arguments 'complements'? Because they complete the idea the verb is conveying. You cannot say what idea "that I couldn't finish them all" is conveying, so it is not a complement. By definition.

Comment: @RoaringFish But prepositions do have valency! To take a non-controversial case consider the preposition *between*. This can't take a singular NP s a Complement, it seems to me.

Answer (score 0):

My reading of it is there are two different meanings.

"I had too many things to do."

Indicates that your workload was over-extended to the point that you could no longer cope.

"I had so many things to do!"

Indicates that you were just extremely busy with your workload, but at an achievable level.